# Export maven project from eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Is there a way to export an entire Maven project from eclipse? I don't just want a jar file, I'm looking for a way that another person can download the entire project with the dependencies and all that already set up the same way that I have it.

Comment: You are saying that this is not yet a Maven project (you are not using Maven), and you want Eclipse to auto-generate the POM file with the dependency information? Where are your dependencies coming from currently?

Comment: It is a maven project already. Right now all my dependencies are saved locally

Comment: So why not just share the Maven project? Do you want to avoid the other person having to install Maven and/or having it download the dependencies?

Answer (score 2):

Just copy the project folder and make the other person import it as an "Existing Eclipse project". If you want to collaborate with that person on it, think of using [Git](https://git-scm.com/) or some other CMS to share it.

Maven will take care of getting the right dependencies.

Comment: Strongly suggest using a system like Git instead of exporting Eclipse projects. But do let Maven take care of getting the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

If you export it as war file then you will not get back maven file. So it is better to just copy the project send it to other person, he/she just need to import as an exist project from path.